# Fetching Array of Arrays from API ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

**Hello Guys!** Hope you are fine I am new to react. I have an endpoint in spring boot and it return me an array of arrays (according to my need). but the problem is when I try to display it on react, it gives me an undefined error.

My API data will look like this;

```
[
 [
   2,
   "fa ",
   23,
  "fajhfl",
  "2021-07-20T06:44:19.000+00:00"
 ],
 [
  4,
  "amdflk",
  35,
  "lafjoil",
  "2021-07-21T06:44:43.000+00:00"
 ],
 [
  5,
  "fasdf",
  88,
  "fajhfl",
  "2021-07-22T06:44:52.000+00:00"
 ],
 [
  6,
  "nm",
  98,
  "faldjf",
  "2021-07-23T06:45:04.000+00:00"
 ]
```

]

My spring boot code is correct with proper use of Cross-origin but for question clarification, I put the Item controller code.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/items")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000", allowedHeaders = "*")
public class ItemController {

    @Autowired
    private ItemService itemService;

    // Get all Items
    @GetMapping("/getItems")
    ResponseEntity<Object> getItems(){
        Object allItems = itemService.getAllItems();
        if(allItems == null){
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        }else{
            return ResponseEntity.ok(allItems);
        }
    }
}
```

Now In react I try to fetch it give me an undefined error,

```
<tbody className={tableStyle.tableBody}>
                    {props.body.map((key) => {
                        props.body[key].map((i, v) => {
                            return (
                                <tr>
                                    <td key={i}>{v}</td>
                                </tr>
                            );
                        });
                })}
```

But seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51898083/11695367) answer, I get the same error

```
TypeError: props.body[key].map is not a function
(anonymous function)
D:/My programming/React JS/Stock Register Managment System/srms/src/Components/GeneralTable/Table.jsx:30
  27 | </thead>
  28 | <tbody className={tableStyle.tableBody}>
  29 |  {Object.keys(props.body).map((key) => {
> 30 |      props.body[key].map((i, v) => {
     | ^  31 |          return (
  32 |              <tr>
  33 |                  <td key={i}>{v}</td>
```

**Thanks In Advance:)**

Comment: You have array of arrays, use `props.body.map` instead of `Object.keys(props.body).map`

Comment: I already use but I want to fetch its data, not just the whole array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below

```js
const data = [
  [2, "fa ", 23, "fajhfl", "2021-07-20T06:44:19.000+00:00"],
  [4, "amdflk", 35, "lafjoil", "2021-07-21T06:44:43.000+00:00"],
  [5, "fasdf", 88, "fajhfl", "2021-07-22T06:44:52.000+00:00"],
  [6, "nm", 98, "faldjf", "2021-07-23T06:45:04.000+00:00"],
];

const Component = (props) => {

  if (!props.data || 
    !Array.isArray(props.data) || 
    props.data.length < 1 || 
    !Array.isArray(props.data[0])) {
   return <div> No results </div>
  }

  return (
    <table>
      {props.data.map((row) => (
        <tr>
          {row.map((col) => (
            <td key={col}>{col}</td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Component data={data} />, document.getElementById("app"))

ReactDOM.render(<Component data={[]} />, document.getElementById("app2"))

ReactDOM.render(<Component data={['some']} />, document.getElementById("app3"))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="app"></div>

<div id="app2"></div>

<div id="app3"></div>
```

Comment: When I run on time its correct all data is shown correctly but when I run it secondly it give me the same error i.e. `row.map is not a function`

Comment: Most likely that, next time data is not coming as array of array. Before return, check for condition if data is not array or array show the empty div.

Comment: @FeezanKhattak, Updated the answer. Check the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are trying to access key from an anonymous. You can directly use `key.map()` instead of an anonymous find > props.body[key]

Please see below:

```
<tbody className={tableStyle.tableBody}>
                        {props.body.map((key) => {
                            key.map((i, v) => {
                                return (
                                    <tr>
                                        <td key={i}>{v}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                );
                            });
                    })}
```

Comment: When I run on time its correct all data is shown correctly but when I run it secondly it gives me the same error i.e. `row.map is not a function`